# How to know when a copy is being created?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get better at understanding the intricacies of C++. I came across this exercise in C++ Best Practices by Jason Turner.

The question is if a copy is being created here.

```
std::map<std::string, int> get_map();
using element_type = std::pair<std::string, int>;
for (const element_type & : get_map())
{
}
```

My answer is yes, because I think std::map isn't explicitly using std::pair to represent the key-value pair. So maybe implicitly the underlying key-value pair is being copied to element_type? How off am I here? Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: I think the answer is yes but for a different reason, a `std::map`'s `value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, Value>` (according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)) so you'll get a temporary because youre lacking the const in your `element_type`.

Comment: If your loop is empty, it might get optimized out and nothing gets copied.

Comment: So then a follow-up question might be "does the converting constructor that makes a `std::pair<std::string, int>` out of a `std::pair<const std::string, int>` copy the underlying `std::string` and/or the underlying `int`?"

Comment: @NathanPierson Hmmm. I'm thinking it would make a const reference of the `const std::string`  and copy the underlying int because it's a trivial type?

Answer (score 2):

In my answer, I'd like to address the question title literally:

> How to know when a copy is being created?

This can be achieved quite easy with a sample class where every constructor in quest makes an output:

```
struct Data {
  Data() { std::cout << "Data::Data()\n"; }
  Data(const Data&) { std::cout << "Data::Data(const Data&)\n"; }
  Data& operator=(const Data&) { std::cout << "Data::operator=(const Data&)\n"; return *this; }
  Data(Data&&) { std::cout << "Data::Data(Data&&)\n"; }
  Data& operator=(Data&&) { std::cout << "Data::operator=(Data&&)\n"; return *this; }
};
```

According to cppreference.com, the copy constructor of [std::pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) is the default, i.e. it just calls the copy constructors of its member variables:

> `pair( const pair& p ) = default;`

Thus, a little MCVE can illustrate the mistake of the OP quite obviously:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct Data {
  Data() { std::cout << "Data::Data()\n"; }
  Data(const Data&) { std::cout << "Data::Data(const Data&)\n"; }
  Data& operator=(const Data&) { std::cout << "Data::operator=(const Data&)\n"; return *this; }
  Data(Data&&) { std::cout << "Data::Data(Data&&)\n"; }
  Data& operator=(Data&&) { std::cout << "Data::operator=(Data&&)\n"; return *this; }
};

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ ; std::cout << std::endl

int main()
{
  DEBUG(std::map<int, Data> aMap = { { 1, Data() }, { 2, Data() } });
  // done like OP -> copy assignment
  DEBUG(for (const std::pair<int, Data>& value : aMap) {
    std::cout << value.first << '\n';
  });
  // without copy assignment
  DEBUG(for (const std::pair<const int, Data>& value : aMap) {
    std::cout << value.first << '\n';
  });
  DEBUG(for (const std::map<int, Data>::value_type& value : aMap) {
    std::cout << value.first << '\n';
  });
}
```

Output:

```
std::map<int, Data> aMap = { { 1, Data() }, { 2, Data() } };
Data::Data()
Data::Data(Data&&)
Data::Data()
Data::Data(Data&&)
Data::Data(const Data&)
Data::Data(const Data&)

for (const std::pair<int, Data>& value : aMap) { std::cout << value.first << '\n'; };
Data::Data(const Data&)
1
Data::Data(const Data&)
2

for (const std::pair<const int, Data>& value : aMap) { std::cout << value.first << '\n'; };
1
2

for (const std::map<int, Data>::value_type& value : aMap) { std::cout << value.first << '\n'; };
1
2
```

[**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca707f5614f5a69d)

Thus, for the first loop (using `std::pair<int, Data>`) the copy constructor of `Data` is called in each iteration.

This doesn't happen for `std::pair<const int, Data>` 
nor for the `std::map<int, Data>::value_type`.

Another simple alternative could have been the usage of `auto`:

```
  for (const auto& value : aMap) {
    std::cout << value.first << '\n';
  }
```

---

Furthermore, I would like to mention the diagnostic of g++ with an even shorter MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct Data { };

int main()
{
  std::map<int, Data> aMap = { { 1, Data() } };
  for (const std::pair<int, Data>& value : aMap) std::cout << value.first << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:36: warning: loop variable 'value' of type 'const std::pair<int, Data>&' binds to a temporary constructed from type 'std::pair<const int, Data>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
    9 |   for (const std::pair<int, Data>& value : aMap) std::cout << value.first << '\n';
      |                                    ^~~~~
main.cpp:9:36: note: use non-reference type 'const std::pair<int, Data>' to make the copy explicit or 'const std::pair<const int, Data>&' to prevent copying
```

[**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ac6c2c9e6bb01c1)

Answer (score 1):

i try this simple code section:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::map<std::string, int> get_map()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> m { {"CPU", 10}, {"GPU", 15} };
  
  return m;
}

int main()
{
    using element_type = std::pair<std::string, int>;
    for (const element_type &e : get_map())
    {
    }
    return 1;
}
```

It does NOT copy, insteady the move is moved. i use https://cppinsights.io/ to get:

```
std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> > > get_map()
{
  std::map<std::string, int> m = std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> > >{std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> >{std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int>{"CPU", 10}, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int>{"GPU", 15}}, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >(), std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> >()} /* NRVO variable */;
  return std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> > >(static_cast<std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> > > &&>(m));
}


int main()
{
  using element_type = std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int>;
  {
    std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> > > && __range1 = get_map();
    std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> > __begin1 = __range1.begin();
    std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> > __end1 = __range1.end();
    for(; operator!=(__begin1, __end1); __begin1.operator++()) {
      const std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int> & e = std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int>(__begin1.operator*());
    }
    
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Hope this help. thx.

Comment: I don't see any move of the key value pair in your exposed code. Furthermore, a move (may) leave the moved-from object in a modified state. That would be a bad facility if any iteration is about to reset the contents of the iterated container...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat, there is a && in the return sentence.

Comment: Now, I know what you meant to say with _insteady the move is moved_. (It reads a bit confusing, and I didn't decode it correctly.) I believe this is the way the compiler considers the temporary caused by `get_map()` returning by value. However, I don't see how this is related to the issue of map _elements_ being copied in range loop what OP is asking about (as far as I understood OPs question)...

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop will use an iterator internally.  Dereferencing an iterator will generate a `value_type` object not a reference to one.  So even though your own loop specifies a reference, it will be a reference to a temporary object that was created (via copy) by the iterator and kept alive by your reference.

Comment: _Dereferencing an iterator will generate a value_type object not a reference to one._ Either I misunderstood this sentence or I don't agree. Dereferencing the `std::map::value_type` _can_ provide a reference: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e88474590ab9b4a)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat no it can't, because it's documented as returning by value not by reference.

Comment: (My deep respect for your high rep. aside...) I still don't get it. Dereferencing an `iterator` should return [std::map::reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), which in turn is `std::map::value_type&`. (Similar for `const_iterator` and `const value_type&`.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat don't let the rep scare you, I make mistakes like everybody else - and I'm not afraid to admit it.  I was using the same reference page you linked, where it clearly says the iterator is to a `value_type` not `reference`.  But if you do a [deep dive into iterator types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) you can indeed find a spot where `*i` is supposed to return a reference and not a value.  So I don't know what to believe anymore.  It seems unlikely to me that the `map` contains a pair that it can return a reference to.

Comment: It surely can return a reference to elements. Otherwise, the overloaded subscript operator of the map wouldn't work, would it? There is no restriction concerning the value of a map's entry - it's just the key which must be immutable. Hence, it makes sense that the `value_type` of a `map<A, B>` is of type `std::pair<const A, B>`. Returning a reference to the `value_type` doesn't break anything as the key (`std::pair::first`) is still `const` qualified.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat the subscript operator returns a reference to `T`, not to `value_type` which is a `std::pair`.

Comment: Nevertheless, the `std::map::operator[]` has to find (or insert) the pair somehow...